# Python 3.11 upgrade - lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: glibc, libc, python-3.11, python-cryptography

Python 3.11 upgrade throws error: lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'xxxxx': /lib64/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /opt/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so).

I get this error while trying to upgrade to Python 3.11

I tried removing Cryptography from requirements.txt no luck.
And tried Python 3.10, same issue. Works fine with Python 3.9

How do i fix it in Python 3.11?

Comment: that library is not compatible with your OS libc, you need to either compile it from source or use a container like `docker` or `LXC` and run python there ... or update your operating system but that's not a real solution.

Comment: Everything works fine with Python 3.9. I am using image: python:3.11 in my Gitlab.yml file and running : 
- pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t ./dist/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/

Comment: because whoever compiled the python 3.9 wheel made it compatible with your OS, but whoever compiled the 3.11 version made it incompatible with your OS, just do as i said.

Comment: `anaconda` also compiles its wheels from source, so if you install it [from anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cryptography) instead of pip it might work on your OS, again the only 100% reliable solution is to use a container.

Comment: Updating Cryptography to 3.48 fixed the issue for Python 3.11

Answer (score 1):

Updating Cryptography to 3.48 fixed the issue for Python 3.11

Comment: Typo: Cryptography to 3.4.8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).